# Transpose a table of numbers in python

Tags: python, transpose

I need to write the data below in python,

```
student score
Bill         43
Suzy       54
Sally       41
```

but I have to flip it too look like

```
student Bill Suzy Sally
score    43   54    41
```

I have this written already,

```
ofile = open('grades','r')
Tfile = open('Tgrades','u')
date = []
while 1:
  a = ofile.readline()
  if a=='':
   break
  data.append(a.split())
```

Comment: The solution that is forming in my head makes heavy use of the `zip` builtin.  Do you know it?  If not, check it out.  It's super useful.

Answer (score 6):

```
with open ('yourfile') as fin:
   lines = (line.split() for line in fin)
   for row in zip(*lines):
       print ' '.join(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Jon Clements' answer shows how to transpose the data once you have it.

You might also want to consider using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read the data in the first place, and you should definitely close your files.

```
import csv
with open('grades') as fin:
    rows = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    transposed = zip(*rows)
    with open('tgrades', 'w') as fout:
        w = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
        w.writerows(transposed)
```

And once you understand what each line is doing, you can make this a lot more concise:

```
import csv
with open('grades') as fin, open('tgrades', 'w') as fout:
    rows = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t').writerows(zip(*rows))
```

---

One thing to keep in mind is that you're not going to get nice spacing for free. Even if you didn't throw away all the spacing that lined things up in the original case, it wouldn't help, because it's the wrong amount. I worked around that by using tabs instead of spaces, which works in this case (as long as you view it in an editor with 8-character tabs), because all of your values and headers are 7 characters or less… but in general, this trick won't work. So, if what you actually want is a human-readable table with nice formatting, rather than a nice compromise between human-readable and machine-readable (which is what CSV is), this isn't the whole answer.

Comment: Unfortunately had to keep my answer short - as typing on a phone is horrible. +1 for your usual detailed answer

Comment: @JonClements: Wow, you actually answer SO questions on a phone? With code? I can't imagine even seriously attempting that, much less giving a useful answer like yours!

Comment: Yeah - a sign of masochism,  stupidity or heavy SO addiction. None of them good characteristics... :'(

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> student =('Billy','Suzy','Sally')
>>> score=(43,54,41)
>>> (student,score)
(('Billy', 'Suzy', 'Sally'), (43, 54, 41))

>>> flipped = zip(*(student,score))
>>> flipped
[('Billy', 43), ('Suzy', 54), ('Sally', 41)]

>>> zip(*flipped)
[('Billy', 'Suzy', 'Sally'), (43, 54, 41)]
```

You can just transpose the matrix with `zip(*matrix)`